# Is there any way to remove the blank space in the last column of listview's columnheader in winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, columnheader

If I maximize my window and set it to dark mode, the white space on the last line will stand out and I want to remove it

Already tried to redraw columnheader

```
ListView.DrawColumnHeader += new DrawListViewColumnHeaderEventHandler(ListView_DrawColumnHeader_Dark);
```

I want to completely delete or hide the part selected by the red box
[here are the pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7PxE.png)

Comment: Should you be using a `ListView` at all? I see a lot of beginners use a `ListView` when they should be using a `DataGridView`.

Comment: My program runs on a local computer and adds at least 100 pieces of data at once. I feel like I should use listview

Comment: Nothing you've said here suggests that a ListView would be better than a DataGridView. Generally speaking, if you're only using Details view and not grouping, you shouldn't be using a ListView over a DataGridView. Apart from anything else, the problem you're asking about doesn't exist with a DataGridView.

Comment: I'm currently looking to remove the marked parts of the image, if that's done I'll add some dynamic grouping based on the data once I'm done with it

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found a better workaround until now, and now my solution is to limit the maximum and minimum size of the window and not allow adjustments, so that it doesn't show extra white space

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).